# What's more common in the spoken English "Isn't it?" or "Isn't it so"?

Tags: sentence-structure, interrogatives

What's more common in the Spoken English (and also in the formal English)

"**Isn't it**?"

or "

"**Isn't it so**?"

Comment: "Isn't it so?" is no longer used (BrE). It is very old-fashioned. I have heard "Is it not?" in spoken BrE, but it's uncommon.

Comment: "Isn't it so?" is also very old-fashioned in American English.

Answer (score 2):

In mainstream British English (and I think in American English as well, but I am not so familiar with that) tag questions overwhelmingly match the person and the number of the subject, so

> They're good, aren't they?
>
> You went yesterday, didn't you?
>
> He shouldn't be there, should he?

There are some dialects which substitute "isn't it" as a fixed phrase whatever the subject: this is a characteristic of some Welsh speakers, and also of some South Asians in the UK. I believe it may be more widespread in Indian English generally, but I'm not sure.

"Isn't it so?" is not a tag question used in the same way: it's more specifically asking for agreement.